Water heater, used to be external, and now internal, any concerns?
This question is about an external patio, which contained the water heater and furnace, in a utility closet off to the side.
The idea is to close off the patio from the outside, turn it into a hallway, and then it becomes internal to the house (with the utility closet on one side of that newly enclosed patio/hallway).
The air intake from the inside of the house would stay the same, but is there any outside air intake or exhaust that I should be concerned about that should be updated? Also there was one vent that was at the bottom of the utility closet that concerned me, I wasn't sure if it's function.
Update 1: This is for gas water heater and furnace.
Thank you

I am assuming they are fuel burning heaters.  If so you want fresh(outside) air intake and exhausts that go outside.  The bottom vent was for fresh air intake.  Newer houses are usually well sealed and fuel burning devices need fresh air intakes.

@crip659 I see, (yes gas water heater and furnace), and from the sound of it, I'll need to route fresh air intake to whatever area is pulling from the bottom vent to compensate for that bottom vent being now internal to the house? (Otherwise everything else can stay the same?)

@crip659 or as long as I add fresh air intake anywhere inside the utility closet that'll suffice? For example, if I route an inlet from the roof to the top of the utility closet.

On the roof, it might be too close to the exhaust.  You do not want to pull exhaust gases back in, where you are living.  Fresh air pipes are usually small, a couple/few inches and go out out the closest wall.  An elbow pointing down outside stops excess cold air from coming in, only what is needed for burning.

@crip659 thank you very much, I have some thoughts on how to achieve that. I'm going to take a look at the area again. If it's ok I might post a follow-up comment to confirm with you.
